# Ant script split file name and extension into 2 separate properties

Tags: ant

I have a fileset that has say 10 files with extensions. I need to then take this and get the filename and extension into 2 separate properties/variables but not sure how. The reason I need to do this as a file starts out on Unix as XB12345.FILE which I need to move to an I/5 system with the file name as XB12345.FILE and the member as FILE.MBR. Most of the files do not have a consistent extension and will only be known at run time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a job for the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) tasks.

The Ant-Contrib tasks have been around for a long time and are quite common to see in Ant projects. The [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task will do what you want. In fact, there's even a [For](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) task that can handle loops.

The `<PropertyRegEx>` task would look something like this:

```
<propertyregex property="base.name"
    input="file.name"
    regexp="(.*)\.(.*)"
    select="\1"/>

<propertyregex property="suffix.name"
    input="file.name"
    regexp="(.*)\.(.*)"
    select="\2"/>
```

Installing the Ant-Contrib tasks is fairly easy if you follow these steps:

- Download the [ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.tar.gz/download).
- Create a directory in the root of your project called `antlib/ac`.
- Put the `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar file in the`antlib/ac` directory.
- Add the task definition.

Like this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/ac"/>
    <classpath>
</taskdef>
```

If you use a version control system, check in the ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar file into your version control system for the project. Now, when someone needs to do a build, they checkout your project, and the Ant Contrib tasks are already defined and the Ant-Contrib jar is there. There's no need for the developer to install Ant-Contrib. Your build just works.

Comment: Thanks David, I am already using ant-contrib and with the for loop it should work perfectly for what I need. Just was not sure if regex was the way to go with this or if there was another Task I was missing.

Comment: You can write directly <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="${basedir}/antlib/ac/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>

Comment: Please replace "regex" by "regexp", see http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/ant-contrib/manual/tasks/propertyregex.html

Answer (score 0):

Though propertyregex is the solution for the intended problem, but you must use override property for you solution.

```
<propertyregex property="base.name"
    input="file.name"
    regexp="(.*)\.(.*)"
    select="\1" override="true"/>

<propertyregex property="suffix.name"
    input="file.name"
    regexp="(.*)\.(.*)"
    select="\2" override="true"/>
```